# div height using php

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a div I need to find the height of. It contains a quasi image gallery. There are 5 images per row, and for the beginning of every row the height needs to increase by `100px`. I am currently doing this:

`<?php
$counter = count(dirFilesAsArray(realpath($flexslider_gallery_path)));  // get the number of files in the directory
$height_per_row = '100';    // 100 px works per 5 images
$images_per_row = '5';
$height = $counter <= $images_per_row ? $height_per_row : floor(($counter)/$images_per_row)*$height_per_row;
?>`

Which is fine, however the code naturally makes it so that when, say, the tenth image is hit, the height goes from `200px` to `300px`. Which although the row is completed, it should not increase to `300px` until the 11th image is added (or a new row is started). I have tried many different things with no good results, I figure the answer might be rather obvious I am just overlooking it. So perhaps one of you has the answer?

[image: Current functionality, notice we have 300px even though the next row hasnt started]

Comment: `$height = ceil($counter/$images_per_row)*$height_per_row;` ?

Comment: damn i even had that initially, but i think some other css thing went wrong that made me change it. thanks for looking it over